# Symmetric matrix is positive semidefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, upper-lower-bounds, positive-semidefinite

Let $A=(a_{ij}) \in M_n(\mathbb R)$ be a symmetric matrix such that:

1. $a_{ij} \in \mathbb Q, \quad \forall i,j=1,...,n$
2. $a_{ii} = 1$,
3. $0 \leq a_{ij} \leq \frac{n-1}{n}, \quad i \neq j$.

I want to prove that such a matrix is positive semidefinite. It is well known that since $A$ is symmetric, this amounts to show that all eigenvalues of $A$  are non-negative. For that, one has to find a lower bound for the eigenvalues of $A$ that is greater or equal to zero. I tried using Gershgorin theorem, but the bound is not strong enough, the same happens with the one on this paper: [https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/henry/reports/bndseigs80.pdf](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/henry/reports/bndseigs80.pdf)

Does anyone one know stronger bounds on eigenvalues of matrices of this kind? Or to prove directly that this matrix is positive semidefinite?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know if I'm missing something, but since $a_{ij}\in\mathbb{N}_0$ and $\frac{n-1}{n}<1$ doesn't your 3rd condition imply that all non diagonal elements are zero?

Comment: Thank you, meant it as $\mathbb Q$. Will edit it now, sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I suspect that what you really *wanted* was to say that $0\le a_{ij}\le \frac{1}{n}$, because then the matrix is diagonally dominant and that guarantees positive definiteness.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not true. Random counterexample:
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&\frac34&0&\frac12\\ \frac34&1&\frac34&0\\ 0&\frac34&1&\frac12\\ \frac12&0&\frac12&1}.
$$
$A$ isn’t positive semidefinite because $\det(A)=-\frac58<0$.

Comment: Thank you so much!