# Symmetric matrix with integer values is positive semidefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, upper-lower-bounds, positive-semidefinite

Disclaimer: This question is a follow-up question to: [Symmetric matrix is positive semidefinite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4792011/symmetric-matrix-is-positive-semidefinite/4792028#4792028).
In here, I tried rephrasing the original problem and made some mistakes in the process. This is the correct version of it. Thank you to all that interacted with my previous post.

Let $A=(a_{ij}) \in M_n(\mathbb R)$ be a symmetric matrix such that:

1. $a_{ij} \in \mathbb N_0, \quad \forall i,j=1,...,n$
2. $a_{ii} = 2n+1$,
3. $0 \leq a_{ij} \leq 2n, \quad i \neq j$.

I want to prove that such a matrix is positive semidefinite. It is well known that since $A$ is symmetric, this amounts to show that all eigenvalues of $A$  are non-negative. For that, one has to find a lower bound for the eigenvalues of $A$ that is greater or equal to zero. I tried using Gershgorin theorem, but the bound is not strong enough, the same happens with the one on this paper: [https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/henry/reports/bndseigs80.pdf](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/henry/reports/bndseigs80.pdf)

Does anyone one know stronger bounds on eigenvalues of matrices of this kind? Or to prove directly that this matrix is positive semidefinite?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Again this is not true.

$$
\det\begin{pmatrix}
9&8&7&6\\
8&9&0&0\\
7&0&9&0\\
6&0&0&9
\end{pmatrix}=-5508.
$$
Also, if you replace the $0$s with $1$s the determinant is $-3248$.

---

**Edit**: A counterexample when $n=3$:
$$
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
7&6&5\\
6&7&1\\
5&1&7
\end{pmatrix}=-31.
$$

Comment: Ahhhhhhh, thank you so much!